# Change skeleton templates in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

is there a way I can change the main skeleton templates in PyCharm?

Whenever I start a new (for example) Flask project I have to alter the skeleton to fit my needs. It would be great if I could say PyCharm to start a new project with a static folder and a template folder, a specific base.html, database template and so on...

Is this somehow possible?

Adding a new skeleton or alter an existing one would be what I need.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of customization is only possible by writing a plugin. The only thing that can be changed without writing a plugin is the main.py that PyCharm generates: it can be changed under Settings | File Templates | Flask Main.

Comment: Oh ok. I just saw that you are a / the dev at JetBrains. So you could see this post as a feature request ;)

Answer (score 3):

I just took a look at the plugin directory, and I think it's probably possible right now, although not for the faint of heart.

Look in PyCharm/plugins/pycharm-flask/ and it looks like there's a jar with the template files in it:

```
bloop:s r$ jar xvf resources_en.jar
  created: META-INF/
extracted: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  created: fileTemplates/
  created: fileTemplates/internal/
extracted: fileTemplates/internal/Flask Main.py.ft

bloop:s r$ cat fileTemplates/internal/Flask\ Main.py.ft
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I replaced the Flask\ Main.py.ft file and it worked for me. Here's how I did it:

I closed PyCharm entirely, no open windows, no running processes, then in a shell:

```
$ cd /Applications/PyCharm.app/plugins/pycharm-flask/lib
$ cp resources_en.jar backup
$ mkdir -p fileTemplates/internal
$ cat >fileTemplates/internal/Flask\ Main.py.ft
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello Custom World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
^D
$ jar -uf resources_en.jar fileTemplates/internal/Flask\ Main.py.ft
```

Then started up PyCharm and started a new project, specifying Flask as the type:

And when it opened up:

[image]

For what it's worth, this method is an extremely hacky means to an end. If you just want to change the default main, this works in a pinch if you're not picky.

If you want to do it the *pro* way, you can get the source code for the Flask plugin from the [Intellij Plugin GIT](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/pycharm-flask). If you follow the [instructions on Jetbrain's webpage](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment) they explain how to download the community version of Intellij and how to build and package plugins.

Comment: It worked for me. I'm updating my answer to reflect the steps.